# HTML symbol as page title with Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I insert this symbol ► into a page title with Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the `►` character in a string.

For example, paste `javascript: void(document.title="◄■►")` into the address bar.

Comment: HTML editor asks me if i want to encode file with UTF-8 if i put it in a JS file ?

Comment: and how to put STAR to title?